# Perl array to variable conversion

Tags: perl

As shown in the code . I have taken a hex number converted to binary , added it to an array and reshuffled .

I want to convert it back to hex and stuck at the step where converting the array to a variable and then to hexa. I have used couple of steps which I comented and they didn't work. Is there a way to convert an array to variable and then to hex for my case

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl
    
    use warnings;
    import math 
    
    
    my $value =  hex ( 'FE300B0' );
    
    print "Dec: ",$value,"\n";
    printf ( "Hex: %X\n", $value );
    my $binval = sprintf ( "%0*b\n",32, $value );
    
    print $binval;
    my @binval_arr = split('', $binval, 32);
    #print "Size: ",scalar @binval_arr,"\n";
    
    #print "\$binval_arr[27] = $binval_arr[27]\n";
    print @binval_arr;
    #my @mod_bin = @binval_arr;
    #my @mod_bin;
    my @mod_bin = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
     
  #modifeid 20..31   
      @mod_bin[20..31] = @binval_arr[20..31];
      @mod_bin[9] = $binval_arr[10];
      @mod_bin[18,19] = @binval_arr[14,15];
      @mod_bin[10..17] = @binval_arr[2..9];
     
    #print join("\n",@binval_arr),"\n";
    print @mod_bin,"\n";
    #my $mod_str = join('', @mod_bin);
    #print $mod_str,"\n";
    
    my $mod_int = int(@mod_bin);
    my $mod_int = \@mod_bin;
    print $mod_int,"\n";


   output :: 
    Dec: 266535088
Hex: FE300B0
00001111111000110000000010110000
00001111111000110000000010110000
00000000010011111111000010110000
ARRAY(0x5635e48dcca8)
```

Comment: What does it mean to "convert an array to a variable"? An array is a variable. What is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: I really got no idea just used import math as it was in some examples. I guess it will include some math functions in the code. I'm not sure in Perl .  So array has elements like @arr=(1,2,3,4,5) instead I needed $arr=12345 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do the binary to hex operation is:

```
$hex = sprintf "%x", oct("0b$binary");
```

To convert an array of "0" and "1" elements into a 32-character scalar of "0" and "1" characters, use

```
$binary = join("", @mod_bin);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be converting to/from binary at all. You should be using bit arithmetic operators.

```perl
my $value = hex( 'FE300B0' );

my $modified =
     ( ( $value >>  2 ) & 0x0FFF ) <<  2
   | ( ( $value >> 21 ) & 0x0001 ) << 22
   | ( ( $value >> 16 ) & 0x0003 ) << 12
   | ( ( $value >> 22 ) & 0x00FF ) << 14;
```

Note that this assigns to bit 13 (`$mod_bin[18]` in the original) twice, just like your code. This is surely a mistake?

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing it out. Pretty weird that in Perl LSB starts from left to right instead of right to left . Or may be I'm missing something here

Comment: Where did you get that idea? Shift right (`>>`) moves bits to positions of reduced significance, and shift left (`<<`) moves bits to positions of increased significance. So, the rightmost bit is the LSB, and the leftmost bit is the MSB. Same with binary (0b1010), decimal (1234) and hex (0x1234) literals. In every possible way, the most sig digit is always on the left, and the least sig digit is always on the right. And this isn't special to Perl. The operators are known the same name in C, C++, C#, Python, JS, Java, etc. And the numeric literals use the same order in all those languages.